# How can I clean up closed tab/window info from current session on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, session-manager

My Firefox (Windows, latest version - 50+, Session Manager Add-on installed) is configured to keep X recently closed tabs per window and Y recently closed windows in the session.

This is something I like, as a way to be able to recover from accidental/thoughtless closing, so **I don't want to set that to zero**.

However, sometimes, I close a gazillion tabs in several windows in an effort to clean up my Firefox, on purpose (this should improve performance and memory utilization).

Problem is, that this same nifty feature will still keep the closed tabs/windows - a lot of them - in the session, because that's what it's set to.

What I'd like is a way to - **ON REQUEST, as one-off** - to clear out my list of recently closed tabs and windows from the current section.

Is there a way to do that? Implementation doesn't matter too much (config file change, restart, add-on, whatever).

Ideally, solution would be more user friendly than to set the size of that list to zero and having to remember to restore it back to what it was before; but absent anything else, if that works, i'll accept that as an answer.

Also, I do NOT want to clean my browsing history. Just the list of closed tabs

Comment: There is a menu command for it : History / Recently Closed Tabs / Clear Closed Tabs List. The same with Closed Windows. Is there a problem with them?

Comment: Have you tried add-on for Firefox called "Session Manager"? That seems to clean up closed tabs and windows list. More details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **This answer was originally written for Firefox Legacy. Additional information for Firefox Quantum may be found at below.**

[Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) is an add-on for Firefox that has the needed feature.

> Session Manager saves and restores the state of all or some windows - either when you want it or automatically at startup and after crashes. It can also automatically save the state of open windows individually.

The description does not explain the feature precisely however, I have confirmed that the add-on can also clean up the closed tabs and closed windows from current session in Firefox. It can clean up the list as separate or both entirely.

The add-on doesn't need to restart after installation or after enable/disable in Firefox Add-on Manager. Upon successful installation, there will be two Toolbar buttons that appear on the left.

Follow these steps to clean up closed tabs and windows:

1. Run Firefox and open few tabs and windows, then close them (if not yet).
2. In the toolbar, click on either one button ("blue floppy" and "red plus" buttons have similar menu).
3. Click on the last entry in the menu **Clear 'Closed' List...**, then click **Yes** to confirm the action in the following dialog.

[image: Clear closed list in Session Manager add-on for Firefox]

Finally, confirm that the list has been cleared. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to show the menubar, and go to **History**. You will find that **Recently Closed Tabs** and **Recently Closed Windows** are now both emptied and disabled in the menu. The following screenshot shows before and after clearing the list.

[image: Clear closed list - before and after]

Tested using Session Manager 0.8.1.12 in Firefox 50.1.0 on Linux. This add-on is available on all systems (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux).

### For Firefox Quantum (version 57+)

Session Manager by Michael Kraft 0.8.1.13 was the last release for Firefox legacy. The add-on has since not been rewritten for Firefox Quantum. So far, no other add-ons can clean up closed tabs and windows (of built-in History rather than extension History) like the legacy add-on could do.

Comment: Awesome answer. Well deserves the bounty!

Comment: Note that the legacy add-on has no equivalent alternative for Firefox 57+ (Firefox Quantum). Notable alternatives [Tab Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-session-manager/) and [MySessions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-sessions/) do not seem to handle built-in History like legacy add-on could do.

Comment: [Too bad they never made a next version after Firefox 56](https://xkcd.com/566/)

Answer (score 1):

Recently closed tabs/windows can be cleared by changing their max quantities in about:config to 0, and restarting Firefox. This may not clear all windows after one restart, so try to restart again. Then restore non-zero values in about:config.

Option names:

- browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo
- browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo

Firefox v111.0.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).